# Disabled products showing in magento1.7.0.2 front end

Tags: php, magento

I am working with magento 1.7.0.2.

I have disabled some products in magento admin and flush all magento cache and reindexed all data properly.but disabled products still showing on magento frontend.

I want only enabled products showing on front end.

Comment: Are you running a multiple store setup? It's possible you can disable on the wrong store and still have them enabled on another..

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer. this is good. Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a Multi-store setup it's possible you have disabled the products for one store font/store/website and not for the website you wanted.

You can enable/disable for each store front separately, or if you select default store from the dropdown store selector in the admin, this will disable for all stores (unless you have also overridden this setting on a lower level).

You could goto the edit product page, and then use the store selector dropdown to check the settings in each store front / store to ensure you have disabled properly.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a probability that your template code has not been implemented logically so your collection is grabbing disabled products as well.

I recommend you to switch to default theme that comes with Magento and check whether those products are still being displayed.

It is assumed that you have deleted cache via admin( recommended that you go into var folder and delete cache folder )